# Attempt to dump FQL logs returned NullPointerException

Tags: cassandra

When I am trying to read data from fullquerylog, encountering java null point exception. Has anyone faced this issue.

- Cassandra version - 4.1
- Host -Linux
- java -11

command used - fqltool dump /home/fullquerylog

```
$ nodetool getfullquerylog
enabled             true                                
log_dir             /home/fullquerylog
archive_command                                         
roll_cycle          HOURLY                              
block               true                                
max_log_size        17179869184                         
max_queue_weight    268435456                           
max_archive_retries 10
```

I tried running below command

```
fqltool dump /home/fullquerylog
```

I was expecting output from the fullquerylog directory.

```
INFO  [main] 2023-03-28 17:07:38,441 InternalAnnouncer.java:46 - Process id: 7940
INFO  [main] 2023-03-28 17:07:38,443 InternalAnnouncer.java:59 - :: Chronicle Queue :: (5.20.123)
error: null
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.BytesStore.wrap(BytesStore.java:76)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.Bytes.wrapForRead(Bytes.java:179)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Dump.appendValuesToStringBuilder(Dump.java:222)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Dump.dumpQuery(Dump.java:179)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Dump.lambda$dump$0(Dump.java:123)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.StoreTailer.readDocument(StoreTailer.java:111)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Dump.dump(Dump.java:148)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.commands.Dump.run(Dump.java:68)
    at org.apache.cassandra.fqltool.FullQueryLogTool.main(FullQueryLogTool.java:65)
```

Comment: do you have logs on the target directory, as this converts binary logs to human-readable format, seems you're pointing to an empty dir

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Comment: Consider adding the "java" tag to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace you posted indicates that there were no logs to convert leading to the `NullPointerException`.

You will need to verify that the node has processed at least one query *after* you enabled [Full Query Logging](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/fqllogging.html). If there were no queries processed by the node then the FQL tool has nothing to `dump`.

Note that FQL logging is enabled on a per-node basis. The query logs will only get generated on nodes where FQL logging is enabled and configured.

You also need to confirm that the Cassandra process has read/write/execute permissions on the FQL directory. If Cassandra cannot write to the directory, it will not be able to generate query logs. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Eric. This explains the error.